# Entity Framework : common method for select data with dynamic where conditions for joined tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like to create a method for common query. This query is joining three tables, and I would like to use property from all tables in the `where` clause.

The problem is when I create predicate on input then I can't implement it on selected anonymous object because all three tables are nested in anonymous object.

How should I implement this common method? I want to have it with different `where` conditions and use only one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common pattern for this is something like:

```
public async Task<IList<QueryResult>> GetQueryResults(
    Expression<Func<Customer,bool>> customerFilter,
    Expression<Func<Project, bool>> projectFilter    )
{
    var q = from c in Set<Customer>().Where(customerFilter)
            join p in Set<Project>().Where(projectFilter)
              on c.Id equals p.Id
            select new QueryResult() { CustomerName = c.Name, ProjectName = p.Name };

    return await q.ToListAsync();

}
```

Which you would call like:

```
var results = await db.GetQueryResults(c => c.Name == "a", p => true);
```

You can give the calling code more power by letting it change the base IQueryables used in the query, eg

```
   public async Task<IList<QueryResult>> GetQueryResults( 
        Func<IQueryable<Customer>, IQueryable<Customer>> customerFilter,
        Func<IQueryable<Project>, IQueryable<Project>> projectFilter )
    {
        var q = from c in customerFilter(Set<Customer>())
                join p in projectFilter(Set<Project>())
                  on c.Id equals p.Id
                select new QueryResult() {  CustomerName = c.Name, ProjectName = p.Name };

        return await q.ToListAsync();
    }
```

which you would call like this:

```
var results = await db.GetQueryResults(c => c.Where(c => c.Name == "a"), p => p);
```

Comment: What if I need c.Property == p.Property ?

Comment: Really there should be navigation properties between the entities.